# xamarin android project access PCL function

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a Cross Platform Xamarin Forms app. In the Portable Class I have a WebView that loads a web page from a URL.

From my Android project, I would like to be able to change the WebView URL.

What is the best way to do this ? I am kind of new to this, so any help to point me in the right direction would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Create a custom renderer for the webview and do it any of the overridden events or use dependency service to trigger the URL change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar scenario in which I wanted to read the received SMS in Android project and send the message to PCL project.
For that I used Xamarin's MessagingCenter:

In Android's activity, upon receiving the SMS, I used the following code to send the SMS message body back to PCL:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<RegisterSecondPage, string>
                            (new RegisterSecondPage(), "OtpReceived", code);
```

And in one of my PCL pages I received it back like this:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<RegisterSecondPage, string>
                (new RegisterSecondPage(), "OtpReceived", async (s, code) =>
            {
                ActivationCode = code;
            });
```

I believe you can use similar scenario as well.

Comment: yes it seems like messaging is the only option here .. strange but hey .. it works - Thank you